# Uploading files with an ImageField and saving them to a static location

Tags: django, django-models, static-files

I have a problem with my app here. My configuration is as such I can upload a new release and symbolically link it for production -- however, this means every time I upload a new release, all of the photos that were uploaded in any parts of my entire project are wrapped into the old release and disappear.

How can I save these files to a static file location which does not get wrapped in the release? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess best for this is keeping your media files out of your source project folder, you could eg have a structure like:

```
myproject
|
|----media
|----src
```

There's no need to have the media folder in the same directory as your source code, apps etc. So you have a solution where the dir with your release only contains static files! The same applies to the database, if you are using sqlite... Have a look at [this](http://blog.zacharyvoase.com/2010/02/03/django-project-conventions/) for a more detailled structure!

Of course this no must, but experience shows it makes live much easier!

Comment: Of course. MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/my_app/production/static_files' is what I currently have, which lives in the same dir as the source code -- thanks :)